# Why can't Unity display text?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Why can't Unity display text?

Why can't the text be displayed on the button?
[image: Unity View]

Tried changing many parameters but still to no avail

I tried installing the font but it didn't work

Does anyone know the reason? Thank you

Comment: because you set it white, and the button is white?

Comment: That's not the reason! I changed the newly added picture to not be white, but I still can't see it.

Comment: then its the layer order

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just create a new poject and it will be normal. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a default button(TMP) again, does the text still remains invisible?
2. Make sure you have installed TMP package correctly.
3. Change your TextMeshPro - Text component's wrapping mode to Disabled, and Overflow to Overflow.
4. Adjust the Pos x, Pos y, Width, Height value in Rect Transform of text to be appropriate.

Comment: Just create a new poject and it will be normal. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand from your problem I think you are using wrong component for text. to show text under a canvas you have to use `TextMeshPro - Text (UI)` but you are using `TextMeshPro - Text` that is used for placing text in 3D Space

place a button from `GameObject/UI/Button - TextMeshPro` menu and see if text still invisible or not.

Comment: Just create a new poject and it will be normal. Thank you everyone.